# How to remove the injected CSS Resource in GWT?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2, clientbundle, cssresource

I want to remove the injected CSSResource in GWT application.

I used the following code `MyClass.INSTANCE.ensureInjected();`

I want the above CSSResource for a particular page only. So the remaining pages should be work as per the actual css/theme.

Once I inject this then its applicable for the whole application. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inject your css bundle using directly `StyleInjector` utility class, instead of  the `ensureInjected()` method

Then you will have a reference of the injected element which you can remove when you want.

```java
// Equivalent to MyClass.INSTANCE.ensureInjected()
StyleElement e  = StyleInjector.injectStylesheet(MyClass.INSTANCE.css().getText());


// Remove the injected css element
e.removeFromParent();
```

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could try to remove the injected style block from the DOM, but this would be quite difficult (and maybe not very reliable).

Much better to organize your 'special' CSS style sheet in a different way:

Turn selectors like

```
.some {
  color: green;
}

.other {
  color: red;
}
```

into

```
.special .some {
  color: green;
}

.special .other {
  color: red;
}
```

and then add/remove the 'special' class e.g. to/from your body element to activate/deactivate the special styles.

Comment: I like this solution, would make the creation of skins quite clean and easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have embedded the same GWT application in more than 1 page and you want a different behavior based on the given page, you can for example call the

```
MyClass.INSTANCE.ensureInjected();
```

if a bootstrap parameter is set.
In the host page, set the parameter, like YourGwtApp.nocahe.js?css=inject and read it as it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351091/pass-parameter-to-gwt-bootstrap-nocache-js-script)
In the onLoadMethod, call the `ensureInjected` accordingly to your bootstrap parameter.

Comment: In an AJAX (or GWT) app, you usually don't really load a different page (which would re-build the DOM), so the injected CSS stays on the page.

Comment: @ChrisLercher unless you wrap it (it = MyClass.INSTANCE.ensureInjected()) in a GWT.runAsynch block

Comment: A runAsync block just means, that the javascript code for that block can be loaded later. But once that code is executed, the injected style element stays in the DOM - until you remove it explicitly (see e.g. @Manolo's answer).

Comment: @ChrisLercher that's true. In the scenario of the question, the runAsync block would be either called or not called at all for a given page. So, the code would be in the DOM only for the page it is really needed. I agree this is not very clean for the wanted feature. IMHO it just fits nicely the given implementation in the question which is not very clean in itself.